# How to insert and select greek words in mysqldb

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, mysql-python

I have create a DB and i use Mysqldb.
I want to insert and select data chars type, and that chars are in greek language.
I have set the collation of my database in utf-8_general_ci but, when i insert a greek word i see something strange characters, then i try to select via python the rows of this table and the result is this `(1,??????)`.

Can anyone help me please?Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with your encoding possibly, make sure to set utf8 in python, and try to set the db:

```
set character_set_database = utf8;
set character_set_server = utf8;
set character_set_system = utf8;
set collation_database = utf8_general_ci;
set collation_server = utf8_general_ci;
set names utf8;
```

Or using a Greek character set :-)

Python:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
use_unicode = True, charset = "utf8",
user=username, passwd=password, db=database)
```

Then to output, you need to specify the string is Unicode:

```
print (yourStringFromDatabase).encode("iso-8859-1")
```

Comment: If you show me an example in python how to use all this you will be the best

Comment: Now i take something like (1, u'\u0391\\u0395\...)

Comment: \\u0391 is capital alpha. \\u0395 is capital epsilon, is this correct?

Comment: You need to specify its Unicode:
print (yourStringFromDatabase).encode("iso-8859-1")

Answer (score 2):

Are you using unicode from Python's side?

> The secret ingredient is to add a charset=”utf8″ to your connection
>   parameters, and use_unicode=True. [Source](http://www.harelmalka.com/?p=81)

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER, passwd=DB_PASS, db=DB_NAME, charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
```

Note that, continuing onwards, while in Python 3 Unicode strings are the norm, in earlier versions, unicode strings and strings are different things.